Does restoring file/folder post delete retain the permissions?
When a file/folder is deleted and then restored, then does it retain the permissions?
Does the behaviour differ if the inheritence is broken or not?

You can easily answer your own question by creating a test file/folder, delete and restore it. Please don't ask us to do things you can easily do yourself.

I'm looking for some authoritative reference and don't want to rely on only testing, hence the question.

The Microsoft Support article Restore deleted items from the site collection recycle bin  does not mention permissions in particular, but any securable object will be restored to its previous state, and in my experience, that does include custom permissions.

If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Unfortunately, there is currently no official documentation that clearly explains this. If you really want an authoritative explanation, it is recommended that you submit feedback to Microsoft.
